# Getting mountain lion

Tags: macos

I have an old Mac pro with lion. It's too old to upgrade to Maverick. Where, if possible, can I get Mountain Lion to upgrade this Mac? I cant find it on the store. I'd like to get a legal version. Even if I have to pay for it.
Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion?find=mountain+lion

From the Apple Store!  (Not the App Store...)

Although, from my understanding, there are no Macs that can run Mountain Lion that cannot *also* run Mavericks.  Mountain Lion dropped support for some older models (with older graphics cards on the whole), but since then support remains the same thus far.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check before if my MacPro can run Mountain Lion.